# signinwithemailandpassword failed first argument email must be a valid string

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm recently practicing React Native with Redux and developing a login form attached to Firebase. The thing is, whenever the signin button is clicked it should give an error above button "authentication failed".

But whenever I tried to click the button, it gives an error: "signinwithemailandpassword failed first argument email must be a valid string".

I've tried hours to solve this but couldn't get the answer.

Here is my code:

LOGINFORM:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { CardSection, Card, Input, Button } from './common';
import { emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser } from '../actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class LoginForm extends Component {
    onEmailChange(text) {
        this.props.emailChanged(text);
        //Its like setState to action, the text is send as a parameter to our action.
    }

    onPasswordChange(text){
        this.props.passwordChanged(text);
    }

    onButtonPress(){
        this.props.loginUser( this.props.email, this.props.password );
    }

    renderError(){
        if (this.props.error){
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                <Text style={ Styles.errorTextStyle }>
                    {this.props.error}
                </Text>
            </View>
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        return(
            <Card>
                <CardSection>
                    <Input
                        label='Email'
                        placeHolder='email@gmail.com'
                        onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
                        value={this.props.email}
                        //What is this function bind to?

                        //Actually, this bind function has a 'this' keyword and 'this' keyword is actually a
                        //parameter that is send to the onEmailChange, 'this' is recieved by 'text' param as the
                        //text written in the email field so its binded and called whenever user writes anything
                        //in the field of email.

                        //We're using 'this' onEmailChange is a call me back (callback) function that will invoke 
                        //when input is pressed or not pressed, that is why we're using bind.
                    />
                </CardSection>

                <CardSection>
                    
                    <Input 
                        secureTextEntry
                        label='Password'
                        placeHolder='password'
                        onChangeText={this.onPasswordChange.bind(this)}
                        value={this.props.password}
                    />
                </CardSection>
                
                {this.renderError()}

                <CardSection>
                    <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}> Login </Button>
                </CardSection>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}

const Styles = {
    errorTextStyle: {
        fontSize: 20,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        color: 'red'
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        email: state.auth.email,
        password: state.auth.password,
        error: state.auth.error
    };
    console.log(state.auth.email);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser })(LoginForm);
//since we connect and added { emailChanged } as action, now we can access this.props.emailChanged.
```

ACTION INDEX FILE:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { EMAIL_CHANGED, PASSWORD_CHANGED, LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS, LOGIN_USER_FAIL } from './types';

export const emailChanged = (text) => {
    return{
        type: EMAIL_CHANGED,
        payload: text
    };
}

export const passwordChanged = (text) => {
    return {
        type: PASSWORD_CHANGED,
        payload: text
    };
}

export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
    return(dispatch) => {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
        .catch(() => { 
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
                .catch(() => loginUserFail(dispatch)); 
            });

    };
};

const loginUserFail = (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER_FAIL });
};

const loginUserSuccess = (dispatch, user) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS, payload: user });
};
```

AUTH REDUCER:

```
import { EMAIL_CHANGED, PASSWORD_CHANGED, LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS, LOGIN_USER_FAIL } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = { email: '', password: '', user: null, error: '' };

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    //switch statement in Reducer
    switch (action.type) {
        case EMAIL_CHANGED: 
            return { ...state, email: action.payload }; 
        case PASSWORD_CHANGED:
            return { ...state, password: action.payload };
        case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, user: action.payload };
        case LOGIN_USER_FAIL:
            return { ...state, error: 'Authentication failed.' };
        default:
            return state; 
    }
};
```

APP.JS

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm'

class App extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        var config = {
            apiKey: 'AIzaSyAjHwCvftP1w0nKJTylUQcXAH-rThhZ6sQ',
            authDomain: 'bold-circuit-429.firebaseapp.com',
            databaseURL: 'https://bold-circuit-429.firebaseio.com',
            projectId: 'bold-circuit-429',
            storageBucket: 'bold-circuit-429.appspot.com',
            messagingSenderId: '270696683683'
          };
          firebase.initializeApp(config);
    }

    render(){
        const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

        return(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <LoginForm />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is your `connect()` function call in LOGINFORM.

I pull out your `{ emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser }` argument you're passing to `connect()` and change it to this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        email: state.auth.email,
        password: state.auth.password,
        error: state.auth.error
    };
    console.log(state.auth.email);
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        emailChanged: (emailAddress) => dispatch(emailChanged(emailAddress),
        passwordChanged: (password) => dispatch(passwordChanged(password)),
        loginUser: (email, password) => dispatch(loginUser(email, password))
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

Your initial attempt used object decomposition to create an object to pass to connect. That object ended up looking like

```
{
    emailChanged: emailChanged,
    passwordChanged: passwordChanged,
    loginUser: loginUser
}
```

My function will take a dispatch argument and map those three values of props (emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser) to functions that dispatch the action to your reducers.

EDIT: Your full LOGINFORM.js file should look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { CardSection, Card, Input, Button } from './common';
import { emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser } from '../actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class LoginForm extends Component {
    onEmailChange(text) {
        this.props.emailChanged(text);
        //Its like setState to action, the text is send as a parameter to our action.
    }

    onPasswordChange(text){
        this.props.passwordChanged(text);
    }

    onButtonPress(){
        this.props.loginUser( this.props.email, this.props.password );
    }

    renderError(){
        if (this.props.error){
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                <Text style={ Styles.errorTextStyle }>
                    {this.props.error}
                </Text>
            </View>
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Card>
                <CardSection>
                    <Input
                        label='Email'
                        placeHolder='email@gmail.com'
                        onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
                        value={this.props.email}
                        //What is this function bind to?

                        //Actually, this bind function has a 'this' keyword and 'this' keyword is actually a
                        //parameter that is send to the onEmailChange, 'this' is recieved by 'text' param as the
                        //text written in the email field so its binded and called whenever user writes anything
                        //in the field of email.

                        //We're using 'this' onEmailChange is a call me back (callback) function that will invoke 
                        //when input is pressed or not pressed, that is why we're using bind.
                    />
                </CardSection>

                <CardSection>

                    <Input 
                        secureTextEntry
                        label='Password'
                        placeHolder='password'
                        onChangeText={this.onPasswordChange.bind(this)}
                        value={this.props.password}
                    />
                </CardSection>

                {this.renderError()}

                <CardSection>
                    <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}> Login </Button>
                </CardSection>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}

const Styles = {
    errorTextStyle: {
        fontSize: 20,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        color: 'red'
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        email: state.auth.email,
        password: state.auth.password,
        error: state.auth.error
    };
    console.log(state.auth.email);
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        emailChanged: (emailAddress) => dispatch(emailChanged(emailAddress),
        passwordChanged: (password) => dispatch(passwordChanged(password)),
        loginUser: (email, password) => dispatch(loginUser(email, password))
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

//since we connect and added { emailChanged } as action, now we can access this.props.emailChanged.

Comment: I understand you a little but you can find my full code here: https://github.com/abrar7866/react-manager-app

Comment: I edited my answer to include the whole LOGINFORM.js file, hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: It still isn't working out. I'm a little newbie in Redux. From what I understand is that you tried to dispatch explicitly but turns out that it is similar to the previous solution, just the another way of doing it?

Comment: After a lot of trial and error, I had a simple silly mistake. I forgot to add the return statement under if block in the renderError method in LoginForm.js. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
onButtonPress(){
    this.props.loginUser( this.props.email, this.props.password );
}
```

wrong call LoginUser function

```
onButtonPress(){
    this.props.loginUser({ this.props.email, this.props.password });
}
```